# SQL Request connection string error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wcf, connection-string

I have written a WCF service with database connection in Visual Studio 2012. When I deploy the  database on my server I get an error:

> The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception
>   message is 'Instance failure.'. See server logs for more details.

I followed the steps from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578196/sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-server-instance-specified-for) to help me but it only helped me to an extent.
My connection string seems to be the problem. My connection string is

```
Data Source=.\\MSSQLSERVER;Database=jarvis;Integrated Security=SSPI;User Id=sa;Password=123
```

The server that I am using is running SQL Server 2012 Developer edition. What courses this problem and how can I fix this?

Comment: If you are using `Integrated Security=SSPI`, then you shouldn't also give it an uid and password

Comment: @Lamak I do. User Id=sa Password=123

Comment: I know, and I'm saying that you shouldn't, either use `Integrated Security=SSPI` or provide an uid and password

Comment: The message says that you have a problem with the Instance name. Are you sure that you have installed SQL Server with the instance name MSSQLSERVER? Perhaps it is SQLEXPRESS? Or just no name "." ?

Comment: @Steve When I use the connection string `Data Source=.;Database=jarvis;Integrated Security=SSPI` I get `The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'Login failed for user 'HOME\BELGARION$`

Comment: That's not a programming problem, but an administration one. Probably your user is not recognized by sql server, Try to add it between the logins and as user of your database. But to do that you need Sql Server Management Studio with an administrative logon

Comment: @Steve How would I go about doing that?

Comment: The server name is BELGARION

Comment: Then don't use integrated security and just provide a valid user and password

Comment: @Lamak Can you please put that as a Answer. It worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your connection string is currently using `Integrated Security=SSPI` and also providing a user and password. You should be only using one of those. Integrated Security means that you use the windows authentication method, so it impersonates the windows user and tries to log in with it (so you shouldn't also provide a user and password). On the other hand, you can use the User Id and password, but without `Integrated Security`.

So, it's either:

```
Data Source=.\\MSSQLSERVER;Database=jarvis;Integrated Security=SSPI
```

Or:

```
Data Source=.\\MSSQLSERVER;Database=jarvis;User Id=sa;Password=123
```

Answer (score 0):

Trial and error just taught me that the problem was "Data Source=.\MSSQLSERVER;" - It's the double \. That's an escape sequence in C#. Everything worked when I switched the connection string to .\MSSQLSERVER.